# Anyone had any experience with JODB for web apps?

Tags: java, database, object

JODB sounds awesome! But is it?

I'm a little wary of using it until hearing from others about it. Should it matter that it hasn't been updated for a while?

Is there other Java direct-object database software other than JODB and db4o that are worth considering?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to adopt an object database? One option is to use the normal SQL database and use Hibernate/JPA as data access layer. They will provide the object oriented nature to the interaction with database.

Comment: You can also look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems

Comment: Haha, you put an answer in the comment and a comment in the answer. Thanks SO MUCH for this EXCELLENT wikipedia link. Relational DB + ORM is just not suitable. There's a lack of flexibility when I want to change the object structure. It's also an unnecessary layer to something that is, essentially, incompatible. I also think relational DBs' days are numbered.

Answer (score 0):

Endeca is an object database that outperforms and out-scales most relational database.

It's pricey though :)

http://www.endeca.com